# Upgrade error from 1.1.1: 'FileMode' exists in both 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

After updating my project to 1.1.1 the following two lines do not work:
`var d = new FileStream(Path.Combine(PathToFile, $"{fileName}.txt"), FileMode.Open);
 var fs = new StreamReader(d,Encoding.UTF8);`

When I reverted the chane to the csproj file, the error disappeared. What am I doing wrong?

I get the following error:

1. Error    CS0433  The type 'StreamReader' exists in both 'System.IO, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
2. Error    CS0433  The type 'FileMode' exists in both 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
3. Error    CS0433  The type 'Encoding' exists in both 'System.Text.Encoding, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
4. Error    CS0433  The type 'Encoding' exists in both 'System.Text.Encoding, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
5. Error    CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IntPtr'

My csproj file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <AssemblyName>Backend</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>Backend</PackageId>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Model\**" />
    <Content Remove="Model\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Model\**" />
    <None Remove="Model\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Engine\Engine.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.1' ">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Previous version:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <AssemblyName>Backend</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>Backend</PackageId>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
    <DockerComposeProjectPath>..\docker-compose.dcproj</DockerComposeProjectPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Model\**" />
    <Content Remove="Model\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Model\**" />
    <None Remove="Model\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Engine\Engine.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="1.1.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.1' ">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="1.0.0-msbuild3-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Previous version contains package reference for `System.IO`

Comment: I tested your suggestion, and it didn't help - I'm still getting an error. What is especially interesting is that the version conflict is based on IO version 4.**1** even though I installed version 4.**3**.

Answer (score 1):

See [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5756#issuecomment-277559393)

> Rebuilding the nuget package fixes it.
>   Go to %USERPROFILE%/.nuget and clear it all.

And [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4484#issuecomment-277863709)

> @ericwj According to joe on web tools team,
>   that’s a known issue. There was one build of the BrowserLink package that had bad references, and **that’s apparently the one that shipped with the .NET Core 1.1 CLI installer**. However, in RC.3, we removed BrowserLink from the Core 1.1 template, so it shouldn’t be an issue with new projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened after installing a SPA template. I had to repair the visual studio so that it can fix the versions.