# The type x exists in both y and z (Visual Studio 2017 and .net Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.1

I have a "file->new project->new asp.net core mvc" (.net Core 1.1) and have installed two Nuget Packages:

- System.Globalization
- System.Text.Encoding

Both version 4.3 as seen in the solution explorer. The error relates to a lower version 4.2. The csproj also references the 4.3 version. So where is the 4.2 ref?
[image]

If I uninstall the 4.3.0 version I get a 4.0.10 and 4.2.0 conflict...

> blabla.cs(117,23): error CS0433: The type 'Encoding' exists in both 'System.Text.Encoding, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

**edit** is this perhaps browserlink related and if so, how can I fix it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43571044/169714

**edit2** @Ilya Chumakov referenced this other stackoverflow topic. So I searched the solution explorer for the globalization or encoding and all I got were references to the 4.3 (which is the nuget version)
[image]
[image]

Comment: similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757769/error-cs0433-the-type-webutility-exists-in-two-places

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by removing the **browserlink** package in the solution explorer under dependencies -> nuget

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4484#issuecomment-277863709

and remove `app.UseBrowserLink();` from `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)` in `Startup.cs`

[image]